# Android SDK version 24 - trouble retrieving AssetManager

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am trying to create a test case to test one of my static methods that takes an AssetManager as a parameter. However, I am having trouble getting the AssetManager class because every on-line blog tells me to use classes that have all been deprecated at sdk version 24. I even tried using the Mockito class to mock my main activity (not sure if thats how its intended to be used) and that returned a null AssetsManager.

How should I go about retrieving the AssetsManager for my project in my unit Test?

Comment: Mockito is usually associated with unit tests in Android. Are you trying to write unit tests (`test/` directory in Android Studio, run outside of Android on the JVM of your development machine) or instrumentation tests (`androidTest/` directory in Android Studio, run on an Android device or emulator)?

Comment: @commonsWare I was only trying to write unit tests, I appreciate the response! The answer below worked for me. I am working out of the test directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test using the `AssetManager` should be placed in `androidTests` (as mentioned in the comments). Then you can do something like this

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class AssetManagerTests {
    private Instrumentation mInstrumentation;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mInstrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testAssets() throws IOException {
        final AssetManager assetManager = mInstrumentation.getTargetContext().getAssets();
        assetManager.open("someappfile");
    }
}
```

In this case the test is opening a file from `assets` but you can do whatever you want.
Notice that the filename is `someappfile` to emphasize that the test is accessing app assets instead of test assets.